# I have created nx workspace with react project as host and one remote app in a microfronted-architecture

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, npx, nx-workspace, nx-monorepo

Upon running `nx g @nx/next:lib my-new-lib --publishable --importPath=@happynrwl/ui-components`  and facing warning`Publishable libraries cannot be used with bundler: 'none'. Defaulting to 'rollup'`. I want to make the lib publishable to NPM soon. What does the error signifies?